# Mathematica online: How to evaluate initialization cells (only)

Tags: mathematica-online

I‘m sometimes (mainly on vacation) Mathematica online on an iPad. Up to now I could not find a way to evaluate the initialization cells (only) which is a menu command in Mathematica on my Mac. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why is this needed? Wouldn't those cells still be evaluated when opening the notebook? Do you want a line of code that calls all cells which are initialization cells?

Comment: @Gladaed: No they are not evaluated when opening the notebook. I need the initialization cells for utility functions, data preparation etc. So it is more than convenient to have them executed seperately - this is what they are made for, isn’t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FrontEndToken` solution won't work because it is not implemented yet.

You could filter `InitializationCell` from `Cells[]`, then scan them with `SelectionMove+SelectionEvaluate`. Unfortunately it seems you can select `CellContents` but not `Cell` so `SelectionEvaluate` won't work...

Assuming you don't need them to generate output you could do:

```
ToExpression @* First @* NotebookRead /@ Select[CurrentValue[#,InitializationCell]&] @ Cells[];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "EvaluateInitialization"]]
```

this works for most FrontEnd interactions.

Comment: Does it work in the cloud? OP is using Mathematica Online.

Comment: This does not work in the cloud.